# Are TypeScript project references helpful with noEmit?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'd like to improve editor interaction speed and the time that `tsc` takes to run over my TypeScript code. One of the standard ways to do this is with [project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html). There have been many reports of teams getting [significant speedups](https://shopify.engineering/migrating-large-typescript-codebases-project-references) by adopting these.

There are a few natural breaks in my code that I could turn into separate projects:

```
root/
  client/
    src/
    test/
  server/
    src/
    test/
  common/
    src/
    test/
```

I have `noEmit` set in my `tsconfig.json` because my workflows generally do not require `tsc` to emit `.js` or `.d.ts` files. I build my client code using Webpack, for example, and I iterate on my server code using `ts-node`. I have TypeScript error checking disabled for both of these ([`--transpileOnly`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#cli-and-programmatic-options)) and primarily check for type errors in VS Code and by running `tsc` as a git pre-push hook.

My understanding was that TypeScript project references required you to emit `.js` and `.d.ts` files. The canonical [project-references-demo](https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh/project-references-demo) project does this. Is this correct? Will VS Code (via `tsserver`) get faster if I adopt project references without emitting JavaScript? Will `tsc --noEmit` get faster, too? Are there any examples of TypeScript projects using `noEmit` that get a significant speedup from adopting project references?

Comment: See [discussion](https://twitter.com/danvdk/status/1395033107888148486) of this question on Twitter. The gist seems to be that it's not very helpful without `.d.ts` emit.

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding was that TypeScript project references required you to emit .js and .d.ts files. The canonical project-references-demo project does this. Is this correct?

I don't think the project references feature ever required emitting JS files to work. However, before version 3.7, it was required to emit type declaration files to get a good IDE experience.

From [the TypeScript 3.7 release notes' section on "Build-Free Editing with Project References"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#build-free-editing-with-project-references):

> TypeScript’s project references provide us with an easy way to break codebases up to give us faster compiles. Unfortunately, editing a project whose dependencies hadn’t been built (or whose output was out of date) meant that the editing experience wouldn’t work well.
>
> In TypeScript 3.7, when opening a project with dependencies, TypeScript will automatically use the source `.ts/.tsx` files instead. This means projects using project references will now see an improved editing experience where semantic operations are up-to-date and “just work”. You can disable this behavior with the compiler option [`disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect) which may be appropriate when working in very large projects where this change may impact editing performance.
>
> You can [read up more about this change by reading up on its pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32028).

And *before* v4.0, incremental builds were not supported with `noEmit`. See [the v4.0 release notes' section on "`--incremental` with `--noEmit`"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#--incremental-with---noemit):

> TypeScript 4.0 allows us to use the [`noEmit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noEmit) flag when while still leveraging [`incremental`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#incremental) compiles. This was previously not allowed, as [`incremental`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#incremental) needs to emit a `.tsbuildinfo` files; however, the use-case to enable faster incremental builds is important enough to enable for all users.
>
> For more details, you can [see the implementing pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39122).

As for performance gains,

Straight from [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html):

> We’re also introducing a new mode for `tsc`, the `--build` flag, that works hand in hand with project references to enable faster TypeScript builds.

The TypeScript team pretty regularly works on changes that improve performance. You can view the rest of their releast notes on their website and you'll see mentions of speedups pretty regularly. For example, see the [3.9 release notes, which has a whole section on speedup Improvements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#speed-improvements), and [the v3.6 release notes, which has a section on "APIs to Support `--build` and `--incremental`"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-6.html#apis-to-support---build-and---incremental) that allow third party tools like Gulp and Webpack to leverage the incremental builds.

Considering that you're using Webpack and associated plugins to do the actual build and that you care about developer tooling performance, have a look at [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/) and the [esbuild loader for Webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esbuild-loader).